# Strapi deletes all the records in the Postgres database randomly

Tags: postgresql, strapi

I have started to use **Strapi** as a CMS for my website. I am using **v4.4.1** currently but I have had this issue with its previous versions as well.

The problem is Strapi deletes all the records in the **Postgres** database connected to it randomly.

I think this happens mostly when its server gets restarted or when I run it in **development mode**.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This is likely to be a strapi problem. Change your db logging to be verbose as possible then check the logs to see what action is causing it.

Comment: It is definitely a Strapi issue but I just posted this question to find a solution for that. I have also contacted the development team.

Comment: @Ali, did you find any solution of this problem?

Comment: Did you find any information?